# ReactNative - How to exclude format when using paste on TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

React Native : 0.61.4

If paste formatted text into my `TextInput`, the styles of `TextInput` are ignored.

```
 <TextInput
    multiline
    scrollEnabled={false}
    inputAccessoryViewID="reviewButton"
    style={{
      fontSize: 20,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginHorizontal: '15%',
      flex: 1,
      textAlignVertical: 'top',
      color: 'black',
    }}
    value={content}
    maxLength={200}
    onChangeText={changeContent}
  />
```

I specified the `color` and `fontSize` in the style of `TextInput`, but when I use paste, the `color` and `fontSize` are different.

How can I remove Text format when pasting?

It only happens on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and try to recreate your case in some famous React native app, I think its can't be possible :)

And btw, in case you haven't notice yet, in Android, there are always two options for pasting including `Paste` and `Paste as plain text`.